# Sending URL in Request body in postman payment integration

Tags: postman

while sending respose url in request body i am getting invalid respose url.

request body:-
{
"merchantId":123456,
 "merchantRefNo":"MRN123",
 "apiVersion":"2.0.0",
 "description":"Testorder",
 "outletId":0,
 "currencyCode":"INR",
 "locale":"EN-US",
 "amount":"260000",
 "responseURL":"https://www.ongoframework.com/web/",
 "customerMobileNumber":"9492850887",
 "billingContactName":"payswiffr",
 "billingAddress":"Billing Address",
 "billingCity":"Hyderabad",
 "billingState":"Telangana",
 "billingPostalCode":"500014",
 "billingCountry":"IND",
 "billingEmail":"BillingMail@gmail.com",
 "shippingContactName":"Shipping Contact",
 "shippingAddress":"Shipping Address",
 "shippingCity":"Hyderabad",
 "shippingState":"Telangana",
 "shippingPostalCode":"500014",
 "shippingCountry":"IND",
 "shippingEmail":"ShippingMail@gmail.com",
 "addlParam1":"",
"addlParam2":"",
"addlParam3":"",
 "paymentMode":1,
 "secureHash":"41D12A60EE895FF4C4012643FE7F60C841D12A60EE895FF4C4012643FE7F60C841D12A60EE895FF4C4012643FE7F60C841D12A60EE895FF4C4012643FE7F60C841D12A60EE895FF4C4012643FE7F60C841D12A60EE895FF4C4012643FE7F60C841D12A60EE895FF4C4012643FE7F60C841D12A60EE895FF4C4012643FE7F60C841D12A60EE895FF4C4012643FE7F60C841D12A60EE895FF4C4012643FE7F60C841D12A60EE895FF4C4012643FE7F60C841D12A60EE895FF4C4012643FE7F60C841D12A60EE895FF4C4012643FE7F60C841D12A60EE895FF4C4012643FE7F60C841D12A60EE895FF4C4012643FE7F60C841D12A60EE895FF4C4012643FE7F60C841D12A60EE895FF4C4012643FE7F60C841D12A60EE895FF4C4012643FE7F60C841D12A60EE895FF4C4012643FE7F60C841D12A60EE895FF4C4012643FE7F60C841D12A60EE895FF4C4012643FE7F60C841D12A60EE895FF4C4012643FE7F60C841D12A60EE895FF4C4012643FE7F60C841D12A60EE895FF4C4012643FE7F60C841D12A60EE895FF4C4012643FE7F60C841D12A60EE895FF4C4012643FE7F60C841D12A60EE895FF4C4012643FE7F60C841D12A60EE895FF4C4012643FE7F60C841D12A60EE895FF4C4012643FE7F60C841D12A60EE895FF4C4012643FE7F60C841D12A60EE895FF4C4012643FE7F60C841D12A60EE895FF4C4012643FE7F60C841D12A60EE895FF4C4012643FE7F60C841D12A60EE895FF4C4012643FE7F60C841D12A60EE895FF4C4012643FE7F60C841D12A60EE895FF4C4012643FE7F60C841D12A60EE895FF4C4012643FE7F60C841D12A60EE895FF4C4012643FE7F60C841D12A60EE895FF4C4012643FE7F60C841D12A60EE895FF4C4012643FE7F60C841D12A60EE895FF4C4012643FE7F60C841D12A60EE895FF4C4012643FE7F60C841D12A60EE895FF4C4012643FE7F60C841D12A60EE895FF4C4012643FE7F60C841D12A60EE895FF4C4012643FE7F60C841D12A60EE895FF4C4012643FE7F60C841D12A60EE895FF4C4012643FE7F60C841D12A60EE895FF4C4012643FE7F60C841D12A60EE895FF4C4012643FE7F60C841D12A60EE895FF4C4012643FE7F60C841D12A60EE895FF4C4012643FE7F60C841D12A60EE895FF4C4012643FE7F60C841D12A60EE895FF4C4012643FE7F60C841D12A60EE895FF4C4012643FE7F60C841D12A60EE895FF4C4012643FE7F60C841D12A60EE895FF4C4012643FE7F60C841D12A60EE895FF4C4012643FE7F60C841D12A60EE895FF4C4012643FE7F60C841D12A60EE895FF4C4012643FE7F60C841D12A60EE895FF4C4012643FE7F60C841D12A60EE895FF4C4012643FE7F60C841D12A60EE895FF4C4012643FE7F60C841D12A60EE895FF4C4012643FE7F60C841D12A60EE895FF4C4012643FE7F60C8",
 "productsList":[{ 
      "productName":"abc",
      "qty":"5",
      "productAmount":"2000"}],
        "cardNumber":"5123456789012346",
        "cardCvv":"123",
        "cardHolderName":"Card Holder",
        "cardBrand":"VISA",
        "cardExpiry":"2105",
        "cardType":"Debit",
        "paymentCode":""

}
response:-
{
    "amount": null,
    "merchantRefNo": null,
    "redirectUrl": null,
    "dateTime": 1581482455254,
    "responseCode": "07",
    "responseMessage": "Invalid Response URL",
    "secureHash": null,
    "formValues": null
}

please tell me that how can i resolve this problem

Comment: post error message.

Comment: please anyone share how to resolve it

Comment: what is the response status ?. This will be there in response body header. status like 200,404,500,201, etc.

Comment: response body status is 200ok

Comment: So this is server problem. not a postman problem.

Comment: check your server side code. are you using any third party api  in your server?